# Adjusting the vertical position of an in-line graphic object in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a set of slides in the beamer environment.  The base of the in-line graphic object in

```
$\alpha(\includegraphics[width=0.3in]{T_n-down.eps})=$
```

is displayed above its line of text. How do I lower it so the base of the object sits on the baseline of the text?  The margins of the graphic object are trimmed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Plesae extend your code fragment to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. Now we can only guess what is your problem. It seems that you need to set image baseline accordingly.

Comment: @Ron Unless you have a very good spam filter, you might want to edit out your email address...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `adjustbox` package and its `valign=...` key. This allows you to specify various different alignments of the image. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
$\alpha(\includegraphics[width=0.3in,valign=c]{example-image-duck})=$ 
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other available values for `valign` are shown in this overview from the [adjustbox documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/adjustbox/0):

[image]

Comment: Good point, Sam. Per your suggestion, I edited out my email address in my posting.  Thank you.

Comment: Mico's suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could encase the `\includegraphics` directive in a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` wrapper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\alpha(\includegraphics[width=0.3in]{T_n-down})=$ 
\quad vs.\ \quad
$\alpha\left(\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.3in]{T_n-down}}}\right)=$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```