Gap Table tblr package
Hello members of this forum:
I have a problem with a table in the 3rd row (header included) there is a gap at the beginning in the last two columns (marked in yellow). Can someone please tell me where this comes from and how I can get rid of it?
MWE:
\documentclass[ngerman, headsepline, 11pt, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx, color, colortbl}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}

\definecolor{lightTableGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.09}
\def\scaleSVG{.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    {\centering\caption{Übersicht der Ausfüllmuster bei der {mna}}}
        \label{tab:3_Uebersicht_der_Ausfuellmuster_bei_der_MNA}
        {\centering
            \begin{tblr}{
                    width=\textwidth,
                    colspec={X[c, h] p{.1\textwidth} p{.34\textwidth} p{.34\textwidth}},
                    vline{1, 3, 4, 5} = .5pt,
                    hline{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16} = .5pt,
                    cells={halign=c},
                    vspan=even,
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries, bg=lightTableGray},
                    column{1, 2}={bg=lightTableGray},
                    %cell{1}{2}={halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white},   
                    rowsep = 1.5mm
                }
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Netzwerkelement & & Gleichungen & Ausfüllmuster \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Leitwert & & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+G(V_p-V_q)+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots+G(V_q-V_p)+\cdots=0 \\
                \end{array}$ & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                    & V_p & V_q & \\
                    p & G & -G &  \\
                    q & -G & G &  \\
                    zb &  &  & \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-a.jpg} & & & \\
                Unab\-hängige Stromquelle & \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-10x16} & $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+I_0+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots-I_0+\cdots=0 \\
                \end{array}$ & $\text{RHS:}\;\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col]
                    p & -I_0  \\
                    q & +I_0  \\
                    zb & \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Widerstand & & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots-i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                    zb: &V_p-V_q=R\cdot i_R \\
                \end{array}$ & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                    & V_p & V_q & i_R \\
                    p & & & 1 \\
                    q & & & -1 \\
                    zb & -1 & 1 & R \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-16x10} & & & \\
        \end{tblr}}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you very much for your help!

Can you make an example which we can compile without having access to your local images?

Can you also mark in your image what gap you'd like to remove?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Without the image the error isn't occuring. That's the problem i'am facing.

Try to replace the image with one from the mwe package

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for the hint. I didn't know this. Now everything should be reproducible and clear - i think.

Did you test the code as it is shown in your question? I get errors because of the undefined macros used.

Do not ask multiple questions in one post!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yeah. I tested it with Overleaf and no errors are occuring.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Overleaf is good at hiding errors. The macro \acs is nevertheless undefined.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I apologize. This is resolved now.

After all that, do you know a solution to the original problem?

Already posted, see the answer below.

As you are anyway loading the adjustbox package, you can use it to change the vertical alignment of the image:
\documentclass[headsepline, 11pt, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx, color, colortbl}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{makecell}



\definecolor{lightTableGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.09}
\def\scaleSVG{.3}

\newcommand{\acs}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    {\centering\caption{Übersicht der Ausfüllmuster bei der {mna}}}
        \label{tab:3_Uebersicht_der_Ausfuellmuster_bei_der_MNA}
        {\centering
            \begin{tblr}{
                    width=\textwidth,
                    colspec={X[c, h] p{.1\textwidth} p{.34\textwidth} p{.34\textwidth}},
                    vline{1, 3, 4, 5} = .5pt,
                    hline{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16} = .5pt,
                    cells={halign=c,valign=m},
                    vspan=even,
                    row{1}={font=\bfseries, bg=lightTableGray},
                    column{1, 2}={bg=lightTableGray},
                    %cell{1}{2}={halign=c,bg=gray,fg=white},   
                    rowsep = 1.5mm
                }
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Netzwerkelement & & Gleichungen & Ausfüllmuster \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Leitwert & & 
                \SetCell[r=2]{c} 
                $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+G(V_p-V_q)+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots+G(V_q-V_p)+\cdots=0 \\
                \end{array}$ 
                & 
                \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                    & V_p & V_q & \\
                    p & G & -G &  \\
                    q & -G & G &  \\
                    \acs{zb} &  &  & \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$
                 \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-a.jpg} & & & \\
                Unab\-hängige Stromquelle & \begin{adjustbox}{valign=m}
                \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-10x16}
                \end{adjustbox} & $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+I_0+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots-I_0+\cdots=0 \\
                \end{array}$ & $\text{RHS:}\;\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col]
                    p & -I_0  \\
                    q & +I_0  \\
                    \acs{zb} & \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} Widerstand & & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{array}{@{} cc @{}}
                    p: &\cdots+i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                    q: &\cdots-i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                    \acs{zb}: &V_p-V_q=R\cdot i_R \\
                \end{array}$ & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                    & V_p & V_q & i_R \\
                    p & & & 1 \\
                    q & & & -1 \\
                    \acs{zb} & -1 & 1 & R \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}$ \\
                \SetCell[c=2]{c} \includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-16x10} & & & \\
        \end{tblr}
        }
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you! Do you have any idea what the problem was?

@FixFox The problem was that you were not using the adjustbox package (or a similar technique) to change the vertical alignment of the image.

I'm a beginner to LaTeX so i am always curious to learn how to do such things properly: What are similar techniques to do that?

@FixFox see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692876/36296 (that's approximately what adjustbox does behind the scenes)

@F. Pantigny The nicematrix package is necessary for the bNiceMatrix used within the table.

Sorry! You are right.

@F.Pantigny to be fair: it was well hidden in all this code :P

With a bit reorganized table preamble, removed all \SetCedll commands from table body and employ tabularray's library amsmath gives a bit shorter code (for exercise):
\documentclass[headsepline, 11pt, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}        
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}



\definecolor{lightTableGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.09}
\def\scaleSVG{.3}

\newcommand{\acs}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Übersicht der Ausfüllmuster bei der {mna}}
\label{tab:3_Uebersicht_der_Ausfuellmuster_bei_der_MNA}
        \centering
    \begin{tblr}{vline{1, 3-5} = .5pt,
                 hline{1, 2, 4, 5, Z} = .5pt,
                 colspec = {Q[c, m,  wd=4em,bg=lightTableGray] X[0.8, c, bg=lightTableGray] 
                            X[1.5, c, mode=math] X[c, mode=math]},
                 cell{1-3, 5,6}{1} = {c=2}{},
                 cell{2,5}{3,4} = {r=2}{},
                 row{1}   ={mode=text, font=\bfseries, bg=lightTableGray},
                  rowsep = 5pt
                }
    Netzwerkelement &   & Gleichungen & Ausfüllmuster \\
    Leitwert        &   &   \begin{aligned}
                                p: &\cdots+G(V_p-V_q)+\cdots=0 \\
                                q: &\cdots+G(V_q-V_p)+\cdots=0 \\
                                \end{aligned} 
                            &   \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                                    & V_p & V_q & \\
                                    p & G & -G &  \\
                                    q & -G & G &  \\
                                    \acs{zb} &  &  & 
                                \end{bNiceMatrix}                   \\
\includegraphics[scale=\scaleSVG, valign=m]{example-image-a} 
                &   &   &                                           \\
Unab\-hängige Stromquelle 
            & \includegraphics[scale=\scaleSVG, valign=m]{example-image-10x16}
                &   \begin{aligned}
                        p: &\cdots+I_0+\cdots=0 \\  
                        q: &\cdots-I_0+\cdots=0 \\
                    \end{aligned} 
                    & \text{RHS:}\;\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-col]
                    p & -I_0  \\
                    q & +I_0  \\
                    \acs{zb} & \\
                \end{bNiceMatrix}                               \\
Widerstand &    &   \begin{aligned}
                        p: &\cdots+i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                        q: &\cdots-i_R+\cdots=0 \\
                        \acs{zb}: &V_p-V_q=R\cdot i_R \\
                    \end{aligned} 
                    &   \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
                            & V_p & V_q & i_R \\
                            p & & & 1 \\
                            q & & & -1 \\
                            \acs{zb} & -1 & 1 & R \\
                        \end{bNiceMatrix} \\
\includegraphics[scale = \scaleSVG]{example-image-16x10} 
                &   &   &                                   \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


